# How to set different text and hoverinfo text

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am working with the plotly package, and I cannot find a way to display different things on the chart itself and in the hoverinfo.
Here is an example of a barchart:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

data(iris)

df <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(n = n(),
            avg = mean(Sepal.Length))

p1 <- plot_ly(data = df,
             x = ~Species,
             y = ~n,
             type = "bar",
             text = ~paste("Species :", Species,
                           "<br> Avg :", avg),
             textposition = "auto",
             hoverinfo = "text")
```

From this code I get this:
[image]
And I would like to display the frequency (n) value in each bar instead of the same thing as the hoverinfo.

I have been looking at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42170476/custom-hoverinfo-text-on-plotly-r-chart-that-is-different-to-the-text-paramete) but the solution described is too complicated for me and I think there must be an easier way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Something like this?

```
p1 <- plot_ly(data = df,
              x = ~Species,
              y = ~n,
              type = "bar",
              text = ~n,
              textposition = "auto",
              hoverinfo = "text",
              hovertext = paste("Species :", df$Species,
                                "<br> Avg :", df$avg))
```

[image]