# Plotting "staircases" using ggplot2/plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, plotly, data-visualization

I am trying to follow this tutorial over here: https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/09/25/survival-analysis-with-r/ (bottom of the page).

I have slightly modified the code for this tutorial and have plotted the "staircases" (i.e. "survival functions", in the below picture "red", "blue", "green") corresponding to 3 of the observations in the data:

```
 library(survival)
    library(dplyr)
    library(ranger)
    library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
    
a = na.omit(lung)
a$ID <- seq_along(a[,1])

r_fit <- ranger(Surv(time,status) ~ age + sex + ph.ecog + ph.karno + pat.karno + meal.cal + wt.loss, data = a, mtry = 4, 
importance = "permutation", splitrule = "extratrees", verbose = TRUE)

death_times <- r_fit$unique.death.times
surv_prob  <-data.frame(r_fit$survival)
avg_prob <- sapply(surv_prob, mean)

plot(r_fit$unique.death.times, r_fit$survival[1,], type = "l", ylim = c(0,1), col = "red", xlab = "Days", ylab = "survival", main = "Survival Curves")

new = a[1:3,]

pred <- predict(r_fit, new, type = 'response')$survival
pred <- data.table(pred)
colnames(pred) <- as.character(r_fit$unique.death.times)

plot(r_fit$unique.death.times, pred[1,], type = "l", col = "red")

lines(r_fit$unique.death.times, r_fit$survival[2,], type = "l", col = "green")

lines(r_fit$unique.death.times, r_fit$survival[3,], type = "l", col = "blue")
```

[image]

From here, I want to make the above plot as "interactive". I want to make so that when you move the mouse over one of the curves:

1. The "properties" belonging to that curve (from object "a") hover (e.g. ID, age, sex, ph.ecog, etc.)
2. In the same "hover box" from 1), also show the x-coordinate (r_fit$unique) and the y-coordinate (from "pred") for each position the mouse is hovering over (for a given curve)

My plan was first to take the "grob" object and convert it to a "ggplot" object, and then to convert the "ggplot" object into a "plotly" object:

```
 grob= plot(r_fit$unique.death.times, pred[1,], type = "l", col = "red")
basic_plot = ggpubr::as_ggplot(grob)
```

But when I try to inspect the "basic_plot", it shows up as "NULL".

```
 ggplot(f)
Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class gg/ggplot
```

Had this worked, I would have eventually converted the ggplot object to plotly:

```
plotly_plot = ggplotly(final_plot)
```

How to make this interactive plot?

I am trying to achieve something similar to this: https://plotly.com/python/v3/ipython-notebooks/survival-analysis-r-vs-python/ (towards the bottom of the page, plot with the title "lifespan of different tumor DNA profiles")

[image]

(Please Note: I am working with a computer that has no USB port or Internet connection, only R with a few pre-installed libraries... I do not have "ggplotify" or "survminer")

Comment: `base` plots do not work as objects like `ggplot`. You might need `as.grob` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplotify/vignettes/ggplotify.html. Or have you tried making the plot in `ggplot` or `plotly` to begin with?

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have ggplotify on my work computer (no internet, no USB port)

Comment: Ah in that case perhaps build the plot in `ggplot` and convert with `ggplotly` (or directly in `plotly`) . I can't look at the moment from my phone but I suspect the issue is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29583945/10142537. Maybe the `grob=plot() ` returns `NULL`?

Comment: Ok, that was the problem, I've added an answer now. The `ggplot` code I've used is a basic example I can improve if you like. It would better fit the `ggplot` grammer for the data to be in a single dataframe (long data) and use one `geom_line` call rather than 3!

Comment: is it possible to change the answer so that : p <- ggplot(var1 = a$ID, var2 = a$age )+
    geom_line(aes(x = r_fit$unique.death.times, y = t(pred[1,])), col = "red") +
    geom_line(aes(x = r_fit$unique.death.times, y = r_fit$survival[2,]), col = "green") +
    geom_line(aes(x = r_fit$unique.death.times, y = r_fit$survival[3,]), col = "blue")
ggplotly(p, tooltip = c( "var1", "var2"))

Comment: thanks QAsena! I edited the original question to ask you something regarding the hover text lables, if you have time, could you please take a look at it. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when you draw a plot in `base` [graphics draw directly on a device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29583945/10142537). The line of your code `grob= plot(r_fit$unique.death.times, pred[1,], type = "l", col = "red")` creates a `NULL` object (unlike `ggplot` which would return a plot object).

You can make the plot directly in `ggplot` (there are a few ways of doing this but I've done a simple example bolow) and convert it with `ggplotly`:

```
fig_dat <- data.frame(time = r_fit$unique.death.times,
                      pred_1 = t(pred[1,]),
                      fit_1 = r_fit$survival[2,],
                      fit_2 = r_fit$survival[3,])

fig_dat_long <- fig_dat %>% pivot_longer(-time, names_to = "pred_fit", values_to = "pred_fit_values")

gg_p <- ggplot(fig_dat_long, aes(x = time, y = pred_fit_values, colour = pred_fit)) +
  geom_line()

ggplotly(gg_p)
```

Alternatively you could also plot in `plotly` directly:

```
fig_dat <- data.frame(time = r_fit$unique.death.times,
                      pred_1 = t(pred[1,]),
                      fit_1 <- r_fit$survival[2,],
                      fit_2 <- r_fit$survival[3,])


fig <- plot_ly(fig_dat, x = ~time, y = ~pred_1, name = 'pred1', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~fit_1, name = 'fit 1', mode = 'lines') 
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~fit_2, name = 'fit 2', mode = 'lines')
```

```
## make dataframe of variables to plot:
fig_dat <- data.frame(time = r_fit$unique.death.times,
                      pred_1 = t(pred[1,]),
                      fit_1 = r_fit$survival[2,],
                      fit_2 = r_fit$survival[3,])

# to include the variables from 'a' we need to put them in the same dataframe for plotting
# Trouble is they are different lengths the predicted data are a little shorter
dim(fig_dat)
dim(a)
# We can join the two with inner join: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right
fig_dat_join <- inner_join(fig_dat, a, by = "time")
dim(fig_dat_join)
# now they are equal dimensions and joined together but we have a slight issue with duplicate values:
sort(a$time) # we can see here that time 53 appears twice for example
a$time[duplicated(a$time)] # this tells us which values in time are duplicated
sort(death_times) # some
death_times[duplicated(death_times)] #none
# because of the duplicates some combinations are returned: see rows 9 and 10
fig_dat_join 

# I'm not familiar with the analysis so I'm not sure what the correct way in this case is to remove the duplicates in 'a' so that the dimentions of 'a' match the output of 'r-fit'
# You might need to look into that but it might not make much difference to the visualisation

# I've not used plotly a great deal so there is probably a better way of doing this but I've done my best and included the links as comments: https://plotly-r.com/overview.html
# labels: https://plotly.com/r/figure-labels/
x_labs <- list(
  title = "Time")

y_labs <- list(
  title = "y axis")

# T include extra info in hovertext: I https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49901771/how-to-set-different-text-and-hoverinfo-text

p1 <- plot_ly(data = fig_dat_join,
              x = ~time,
              # text = ~n,
              # textposition = "auto",
              # hoverinfo = "text",
              hovertext = paste("Time :", fig_dat_join$time,
                                "<br> Sex :", fig_dat_join$sex,
                                "<br> Inst :", fig_dat_join$inst,
                                "<br> ID :", fig_dat_join$ID,
                                "<br> Age :", fig_dat_join$age
                                )) %>% 
  add_trace(y = ~pred_1,
            type = 'scatter',
            name = 'Predictor 1',
            mode = 'lines') %>% 
  add_trace( y = ~fit_1,
            type = 'scatter',
            name = 'Fit 1',
            mode = 'lines') %>% 
  add_trace( y = ~fit_2,
             type = 'scatter',
             name = 'Fit 2',
             mode = 'lines') %>% 
  layout(xaxis = x_labs, yaxis = y_labs)

p1
```

I was making dataframe `a` match up with the `unique.death.times` by using `left_join()` above. If you don't need that then we could just move the `hovertext` code into each `add_trace`?

```
fig_dat <- data.frame(time = r_fit$unique.death.times,
                      pred_1 = t(pred[1,]),
                      fit_1 = r_fit$survival[2,],
                      fit_2 = r_fit$survival[3,])


p2 <- plot_ly(data = fig_dat,
              x = ~time,
              # text = ~n,
              # textposition = "auto",
              hoverinfo = "text"
) %>% 
  add_trace(y = ~pred_1,
            type = 'scatter',
            name = 'Predictor 1',
            mode = 'lines',
            hovertext = paste("Time :", fig_dat$time,
                              "<br> y axis :", fig_dat$pred_1,
                              "<br> Sex :", a$sex[1],
                              "<br> Inst :", a$inst[1],
                              "<br> ID :", a$ID[1],
                              "<br> Age :", a$age[1]
            )) %>% 
  add_trace( y = ~fit_1,
             type = 'scatter',
             name = 'Fit 1',
             mode = 'lines',
             hovertext = paste("Time :", fig_dat$time,
                               "<br> y axis :", fig_dat$fit_1,
                               "<br> Sex :", a$sex[2],
                               "<br> Inst :", a$inst[2],
                               "<br> ID :", a$ID[2],
                               "<br> Age :", a$age[2]
             )) %>% 
  add_trace( y = ~fit_2,
             type = 'scatter',
             name = 'Fit 2',
             mode = 'lines',
             hovertext = paste("Time :", fig_dat$time,
                               "<br> y axis :", fig_dat$fit_2,
                               "<br> Sex :", a$sex[3],
                               "<br> Inst :", a$inst[3],
                               "<br> ID :", a$ID[3],
                               "<br> Age :", a$age[3]
             )) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = x_labs, yaxis = y_labs)

p2
```

Comment: Happy Christmas! Thank you so much - this is the best Christmas gift I could have asked for! Just 2 questions : 1) in the hover text, how do you change the title for "r_fit$survival" to "y-axis"? 2) To the hover text, can you also add information from the "a" object (e.g. age, sex, id, ph.ecog, etc)? Thanks, and Happy Christmas!

Comment: is it possible to change the answer so that : p <- ggplot(var1 = a$ID, var2 = a$age )+
    geom_line(aes(x = r_fit$unique.death.times, y = t(pred[1,])), col = "red") +
    geom_line(aes(x = r_fit$unique.death.times, y = r_fit$survival[2,]), col = "green") +
    geom_line(aes(x = r_fit$unique.death.times, y = r_fit$survival[3,]), col = "blue")
ggplotly(p, tooltip = c( "var1", "var2"))

Comment: I updated to include a answer that works for plotly. Just saw your comment for ggplot. I'll see if I can get to that too.

Comment: Ok, I've changed the ggplot code above. ggplot likes long data but after converting to with `ggplotly()` I'm not sure how to adjust the hovertext... Maybe go with the `plotly` code XD

Comment: thanks QAsena! I edited the original question to ask you something regarding the hover text lables, if you have time, could you please take a look at it. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't get that part. I thought it was one value per time. In that case we can forget the `join` I think. Is the new update what you need? Each `add_trace` references a predictor or fit now and also references the first second or third index of dataframe `a`.  You might want to double check some values to see if they match what you expect!

Comment: Hello QAsena! I posted a new question relating to plotly - if possible, could you please take a look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65679523/r-obtaining-rules-from-a-function

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I can help with your new question. Not familiar with the package and sadly I won't be able to dig into it at the moment!

Comment: @QAsena : great answer! if you have time, can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68242473/r-adding-a-tool-tip-to-interactive-plot-plotly thanks