# R plotly: Customize Hover (Info and Text)

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I would like to customize what I see in plotly when I hover on a bar.

Please have a look at the reprex at the end of the post.
I had a look at

[How to set different text and hoverinfo text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49901771/how-to-set-different-text-and-hoverinfo-text)

https://community.rstudio.com/t/changing-hovertext-in-plotly/71736

But I must be making some mistake.
What I would like is to see only the variables "macro_sector" and "amount" when I hover on a bar and no static text on the bar at all.
How can I achieve that? Many thanks

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(plotly)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'plotly'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     last_plot
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
#> The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     layout


df <- structure(list(macro_sector = c("U Activities of extraterritorial organisations and bodies", 
"T Activities of households as employers; u0ndifferentiated goods- and services-producing activities of households for own use", 
"P Education", "O Public administration and defence; compulsory social security", 
"K Financial and insurance activities", "S Other service activities", 
"A Agriculture, forestry and fishing", "L Real estate activities", 
"Q Human health and social work activities", "B Mining and quarrying ", 
"E Water supply; sewerage, waste management and remediation activities", 
"R Arts, entertainment and recreation", "F Construction", "I Accommodation and food service activities", 
"M Professional, scientific and technical activities", "J Information and communication", 
"N Administrative and support service activities", "G Wholesale and retail trade; repair of motor vehicles and motorcycles", 
"D Electricity, gas, steam and air conditioning supply", "H Transportation and storage", 
"C Manufacturing"), amount = c(2.2935, 17.6690005, 204.47243683, 
347.24800021, 400.12333973, 613.6673475, 657.3337123, 672.74723757, 
736.05549391, 828.06106689, 961.82905534, 1538.40117934, 1918.77325865, 
2397.02875187, 3941.39973575, 4735.36088945, 5025.39834121, 5913.94010435, 
10267.76691901, 12407.11032805, 35782.07991161), macro_sector1 = structure(1:21, .Label = c("U", 
"T", "P", "O", "K", "S", "A", "L", "Q", "B", "E", "R", "F", "I", 
"M", "J", "N", "G", "D", "H", "C"), class = "factor")), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                  "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -21L)) %>%
    mutate(amount=round(amount, 2))

       fig <-  plot_ly(df,
                       x = ~amount, y = ~macro_sector1,
                       type = 'bar' ,
                       text= ~paste0(macro_sector, "<br>", amount),
                       hoverinfo= text ## ,
                       ## hovertext = text
                       )
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `hoverinfo` parameter `"text"` needs to be quoted:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

DF <- structure(list(macro_sector = c("U Activities of extraterritorial
                     organisations and bodies", "T Activities of households as employers;
                     u0ndifferentiated goods- and services-producing activities of households for
                     own use", "P Education", "O Public administration and defence; compulsory
                     social security", "K Financial and insurance activities", "S Other service
                     activities", "A Agriculture, forestry and fishing", "L Real estate
                     activities", "Q Human health and social work activities", "B Mining and
                     quarrying ", "E Water supply; sewerage, waste management and remediation
                     activities", "R Arts, entertainment and recreation", "F Construction", "I
                     Accommodation and food service activities", "M Professional, scientific and
                     technical activities", "J Information and communication", "N Administrative
                     and support service activities", "G Wholesale and retail trade; repair of
                     motor vehicles and motorcycles", "D Electricity, gas, steam and air
                     conditioning supply", "H Transportation and storage", "C Manufacturing"),
                     amount = c(2.2935, 17.6690005, 204.47243683, 347.24800021, 400.12333973,
                     613.6673475, 657.3337123, 672.74723757, 736.05549391, 828.06106689,
                     961.82905534, 1538.40117934, 1918.77325865, 2397.02875187, 3941.39973575,
                     4735.36088945, 5025.39834121, 5913.94010435, 10267.76691901, 12407.11032805,
                     35782.07991161), macro_sector1 = structure(1:21, .Label = c("U", "T", "P",
                     "O", "K", "S", "A", "L", "Q", "B", "E", "R", "F", "I", "M", "J", "N", "G",
                     "D", "H", "C"), class = "factor")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
                     row.names = c(NA, -21L)) %>% mutate(amount=round(amount, 2))

fig <-  plot_ly(DF,
                x = ~ amount,
                y = ~ macro_sector1,
                type = 'bar',
                hovertext = ~ paste0(macro_sector, "<br>", amount),
                hoverinfo = "text")
fig
```

[image: result]

**From the docs:**

[text](https://plotly.com/r/reference/bar/#bar-text):

> Sets text elements associated with each (x,y) pair. If a single
> string, the same string appears over all the data points. If an array
> of string, the items are mapped in order to the this trace's (x,y)
> coordinates. If trace `hoverinfo` contains a "text" flag and
> "hovertext" is not set, these elements will be seen in the hover
> labels.

[hovertext](https://plotly.com/r/reference/bar/#bar-hovertext):

> Sets hover text elements associated with each (x,y) pair. If a single
> string, the same string appears over all the data points. If an array
> of string, the items are mapped in order to the this trace's (x,y)
> coordinates. To be seen, trace `hoverinfo` must contain a "text" flag.